# Swift: prevent cells with text in UITableViewCell from being re-initialized after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, uiscrollview

In my iOS app I have a UITableViewController with many cells and some of them contain a UITextField so that the user can insert text. The "problem" is that if, after entering the text in the right cell, the user scrolls down the table and then scrolls up it, then those cells are initialized again and the text il blank again. Is there a way to prevent this? So that the cells are initialized only when the table is scrolled down... Thank you

Comment: You can make your `UITableViewCell` class listening to `UITextFieldDelegate` and handle `textFieldEditingDidEnd` event. Then you can fire your custom event to `UITableViewController` having text entered and the row where it happened. Then you can store this data locally within `UITableViewController`  and assign it back at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @teamnorge You should make that an answer because that is the proper solution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion...I am afraid I need some code or a tutorial because I am very new to iOS programming and I don't know about many things you mentioned in your comment...

Comment: I have just seen that the problem concerns also the picker view and the date picker view...they are re-initialized again :(

Comment: @rmaddy I am less experienced in Swift, but I can easily make the Objective-C code sample. But will it be useful to OP  :)

Comment: this http://pastebin.com/04184AJD is my swift class source if it can help. There are things I don't understand...each cell of my table is a property of the class. When scrolling down all the properties are initialized in the correct order but if I scroll up it seems that they exchange their content each other...

Comment: @teamnorge if you want, would you please write the objective c code you'd use? I understand a little of objective c and maybe I'm able to translate it into swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to my comment to the initial code and code provided.

Many developers implement `UITableViewDatasource` methods in a natural way. 
Put inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` a conditional `switch/case` block and dependent on `indexPath.row` dequeue and return reusable cell. This is ok, but this also means that you need to put one more `switch/case` block into `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and probably into `numberOfRowsInSection` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

What if you are in need of changing the order of cells in tableview, or in need of inserting new cell in between existing cells or something else. This cause to the significant rewrite of the existing code.

The good practice for the the predefined tableviews (known amount and order of rows) is to create an Object describing tableview cells and access it from all those `UITableViewDatasource`, `UITableViewDelegate` methods. This Object also could be used for storing the value of the dynamic elements in cells and could be updated accordingly.

Let say it's an array of NSDictionary's (mutable once if we decide to store data inside).

```
let cellsData : [[String: String]] = [["type": "TextField","value": ""], ["type": "DatePicker","value": ""], ["type": "TextField","value": "Default Value"]]
```

In your `UITableViewDatasource`, `UITableViewDelegate` method you access your `cellsData` array using `indexPath.row` get the `NSDictionary` object parse it, and dependent on the value of "type" key, dequeue proper cell. You will also have to `switch/case` block everywhere, but you check the value from `cellsData` Object not indexPath.row itself. So you can update you tableview, just by updating `cellsData` object. You can also put `height` into it etc.

I see you keep references from cells dequeued in tableview, for accessing them to retrieve data, but it's not needed if you have all actual data stored in the `cellsData` Object.
How to achieve it? Listen to events inside cell. Create custom events, and trigger them from cell.

To create custom event, you will need to create your custom `delegate` class (Reference [Implementing a Delegate for a Custom Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11))

The Swift concept is very similar to Objective-C. First we need to create the delegate protocol class:

```
protocol BigTextCellDelegate {
    func controller(controller: BigTextCell, textFieldDidEndEditingWithText: String, atIndex: Int)
}
```

Then you need to declare a delegate property inside your custom cell class.

```
var delegate: BigTextCellDelegate?
```

Now you need to implement it in your tableview class, first make your tableview class conforming to `BigTextCellDelegate` protocol in a way.

```
class DetailsNewTaskViewController: UITableViewController, BigTextCellDelegate {
...
}
```

Then we need to implement `BigTextCellDelegate`, just place a method inside `DetailsNewTaskViewController`.

```
func controller(controller: BigTextCell, textFieldDidEndEditingWithText: String, atIndex: indexRow) {
// @todo: update `cellsData` at indexRow with `textFieldDidEndEditingWithText` text
}
```

Now you need to make your custom cell to listed to `UITextFieldDelegate` events and trigger our custom `BigTextCellDelegate` event. 
First you need to make it conforming to `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and then assign it during the initialization, you can achieve the same from Storyboard.

```
class BigTextCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
var Int: rowIndex
var delegate: BigTextCellDelegate?

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    textField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    delegate?.controller(self, textFieldDidEndEditingWithText: textField.text, atIndex: rowIndex)
}
```

}

The delegate property of type `BigTextCellDelegate` is optional as we can't be sure it's not nil.

Now you need to assign your tableview to listen to `BigTextCellDelegate` events.

At `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, put:

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(...)
cell.delegate = self
cell.rowIndex = indexPath.row
```

// @todo: get data from cellsData array and assign it back to cell.textField.text

That's all.

As for the DatePicker and other cells. You can do it exactly in the same way. 
Assign to valueChanged of DatePicker from inside the cell and trigger the method on new custom delegate protocol.

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dataPickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {
// @todo: trigger event
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your detailed and precise answer, very kind of yours. I admit there are some things I don't understand but this is due to my inexperience. I'll try to put in practice what you wrote. So, my table view controller class should implement all the methods of all protocols, right? A protocol for each "kind" of my table view cell (the one with big text, the one with little text, the one with the switcher, the one with data picker view and the one with the date picker view)...right?

Comment: @LoryLory you do not need to create custom protocols for each of your custom cell, just for the same type of cells. So if your big one, little one, etc. are having textfields inside, you can create one protocol `TextCellDelegate` and trigger it from your cells. As you can see in the protocol method there is a reference to cell, make it of the type of `UITableViewCell` or even just id. Then you can handle not only the row triggered event from tableview controller but even the type of cell. But you can obtain this info from `cellsData` array also.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not making it and now i have the project full of errors. I can't create an unique custom protocols because some cells have got a UITextView while others have got UITextField. So at least I need two protocols but I'm not able to put al together...if you can give me some more of your help....

Comment: You custom protocol has no relation to the cell structure. You should make the cell class itself conforming to certain protocol depending on structure, extract text entered as String (differently for UITextField and UITextView) and trigger your custom delegate method `controller: textFieldDidEndEditingWithText:` with String. For the cells with `UITextView` you should use `UITextViewDelegate` and implement `textViewDidEndEditing`. I think you should also put your protocol into a separate file.

Comment: Inside the custom cell class the method you wrote

Comment: required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    textField.delegate = self
}

Comment: ends with this: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: maybe I should initialize it in another way?

Comment: that's up to you, I have no ideas what's the structure of your custom cells, if you use Storyboard then this will not work of course and you need to implement `initWithCoder` method instead. The important thing here is that you need to place `textField.delegate = self` somewhere inside your `init` in this way you subscribe your cell class to listed to `UITextFieldDelegate ` notifications like: `textFieldDidEndEditing`, alternatively you can just do it by connecting two points in Storyboard editor. I would suggest to google for it, there are so many good examples available.

Comment: if inside my cell I have a switcher, which method should I implement as listener?

Comment: You do not need to conform any delegate, you can assign a method to listen to its `UIControlEventValueChanged` from inside init method  `mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("stateChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)`

`func stateChanged(switchState: UISwitch) { /* trigger custom event*/ }` but please Google for such questions first.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day!